# Just uploaded Android App: How long before app shows in Android Market search?

Tags: android, google-play

I've just uploaded a new app to the android market. However when I try to download it to my phone through the Android market, it doesn't appear!

Please can someone with knowledge of this let me know how I can get my app to appear in the search results.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=5fae654e5bf022c2&hl=en

Comment: Yep seems atleast for india takes about 2-3 hours till it's on the market.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Android Play app store and its policies, and not a specific programming question or tool.

Comment: @BradLarson the question seems to be reasonable and it relates to android development. I don't understand why it was marked as off-topic. Can we consider to reopen it? I'd like to post an answer, but I have just realized it was closed

Comment: @opewix - It's been six years since I handled the flag on this calling for it to be closed, and I still defer to the community in the decision that non-code-related app store questions are generally considered off topic for the site. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for where this has been discussed in depth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be instantaneous (at least it usually is for me).
Is the app not offered to you at all? Could one of your settings in AndroidManifest.xml prevent it from being offered to you by the market?

Comment: Should be instantaneous???

Well not quite! It's showing up now. Had to wait 10 minutes or so. Phew! I think I had to wait for google's search index table to get updated.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Actually, it is instantaneous. You had to wait for your phones cache of the market data to be marked as stale...

Comment: Please also take note of @speedplane's answer: he states "show up" != searchable, and points out how to actually find your app while it's not findable by searching.

Comment: I've had to wait an hour or two for it to "show up" (see @speedplane's answer), both on initial upload and when updating an app. It's never been instantaneous for me, but it does eventually show up in the Market web site and in devices.

Comment: @Eamorr 10 minutes? I'm waiting 20 hours now... Is this normal? Since your original question is almost 4 years old.

Comment: Sometime it takes around 48 hours.But normally 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 47):

It does instantly show up in the market, but it may take a while for it to become searchable. You can access your market page instantaneously by going to the following page:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[your app package name]

e.g.:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedplane.androidvideoapp

Comment: FWIW, when I initially uploaded my app, the market webpage did not appear for about 45 minutes, and when I updated my app, the old version stayed on the market webpage for a couple of hours. YMMV

Comment: New Google play url format https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.orizin.whattowatch

Answer (score 9):

It might take a bit of time. While it's supposed to be instantaneous, that's not always the case. Once I had to wait a couple of hours for it to show up on my phone (but I believe that was abnormal behavior).

Don't forget to check the Android Manifest file as @chiranjib mentioned as well.

Answer (score 5):

Check the Android manifest file with the following properties

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="19"  />
<supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Refer to the following link
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=5fae654e5bf022c2&hl=en

Comment: Do you need the <supports-screens/> tag?  I published about an hour ago and don't see it yet, but it says it is supported on 1,312 devices in the developer console.  I thought that if you do not add the supports-screens tag it takes the defaults of supporting all screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find your answer here (discussion about your problem) : http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=3bb960d59eba7d04&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=[yourapp]

try this, the old search engine doesn't work anymore.

Mine is showing up on there, but not on my phone yet. I guess its a waiting game.