# Google Play Developer Console: App stuck in "Processing Update"

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I'm trying to update version 20 of my app. Usually it takes no more than 2 hours for the update to go live. However, I have been waiting 36 hours. Should I resubmit my app?

Comment: Just finished processing.

Comment: Facing same issue.. Still stuck on it..

Comment: Would that be 40 hrs total?

Comment: Me too, 20 hours, is there any official communication?

Comment: 10 hours so far...

Comment: At first, It wouldn't work. But then I updated to Android Studio 2.2.3 and changed my `compileSdkVersion` to 25 and submitted. It still took some time but it finally went through.

Comment: My update is stuck too.

Comment: me too, I have been waiting for 72 hours

Comment: mine took 3 days.

Comment: @grant how you problem got resolved, i also have the same issue i have already updated 20 update all where success, but my new update is stuck on processing. itsbeen 3 days no changes. please help me how do i resolve this issue

Comment: @SamwinishereHere It's usually the fault of Google's servers. But I think changing the version code and version name in my app helped as well as updating the store listing description. Good Luck!

Comment: for me updating the store listing description seemed like has been unstuck the app review

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stuck on app status "`Processing update`" with the `RESUBMIT APP` button *grayed out*, here's what I did to force resubmitting the app:

1. Go to `Store Presence` -> `Pricing & distribution`;
2. Change **country** `X` (any) from `Available` to `Unavailable`;
3. Once the change is done, the `RESUBMIT APP` will be enabled gain;
4. Change **country** `X` to `Available` again.

---

This may work by changing other app info, you'll have to try.

Answer (score 2):

The version of the app as far as I know does not affect anything to the speed of the approval. Try re-submitting the update to the developer console again, there might be a hiccup.

Moreover, [here's another StackOverFlow discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863660/just-uploaded-android-app-how-long-before-app-shows-in-android-market-search)

> This should be instantaneous (at least it usually is for me). Is the app not offered to you at all? Could one of your settings in AndroidManifest.xml prevent it from being offered to you by the market? via [@Heiko Rupp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100957/heiko-rupp)

Comment: It's been more than 24 hours in my case. I had uploaded the apk in alpha mode but due to some reason I couldn't make it to production. Now after around 1 year I submit an alpha release to my alpha testing with higher version number and it's getting stucked at processing your update.

Comment: I still waiting for more than a week

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix
In my case its covid 19 time ao usually it took longer like 3 4 days for every review

My main app's version 23 was submitted for review in covid time (aug 2020)

In this mean time i cross checked how long it takes by simply removing adding available countries list for 3 of my old apps
All apps are reviewed in 24hours

So i thought my main app also be reviewed in 24houts but unfortunately it took 3days to come live

Main app's version24 was submitted next day
it took 4hours to reviewed

But next day my version 25 was submitted but my app was stuck at "processing review" for 7days

The point i did is i removed some countries in available countries list and submitted for review (as i did for my secondary dummy apps)

Boom it was reviewed in 5hours

(Before changing the countries list for my main app, I've talked with developers conaole chat, but they recommended me to not to do any changes,but i lost patience as my app is not visible in playstore for 7 days so with brave i changed the countries list and it really worked)

Comment: Which countries did you removed?

Comment: @HussainDehgamwala u can remove any country that u feel dont want,then once ur app is approved u can re add the country any time,but do not submit the app for review ater evening in ur local time,try to publish in mrng 10 to 12,ive successfully published arround 6 versions by this time in india,but if i submit in evening or night (after 7pm),then my app will get into same stuck process,then i have to remove a country in nxt day mrng 10am to make it fastly approved //its all due to work from home i think

Comment: I send two apps in at the same time in12 February, one of them I just adding it to internal test and the sec for the full rollout, after some changes an uploading 3 version of the first app then send them all to a full rollout, now the second one it's approved but the first one still stuck in reviewing process for 3 versions, is there something I do to get be approved?

Comment: No, recently I had these type of experiences. its not in your countroll. Keep in mind, if it takes time to be reviewed, then they are reviewing your app's title,description,and contents if your app is violating any google play policies. Once they verify your app will come live, for me it took 10 days one time and 4 days one time.